# How to get a treewalker to skip elements where a user writes text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, lexical

[Lexical](https://lexical.dev/) is a JavaScript text editor that doesn't use the standard input tags to type the text in.

I have created a chrome extension where I do a word find and replace by targeting `node.textContent`. I'd like to omit text typed inside the lexical text editor.

```
function replaceBadWords(node, searchedWord, replacement) {
  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    const node = treeWalker.currentNode;
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(searchedWord, replacement);
  }
}
replaceBaddWords(document.body,`badWord`, `goodWord`);
```

Comment: Add filter like `n=>n.contentEditable?2:1` or `n=>n.parentNode.closest('contenteditable=true]')?3:1` to createTreeWalker.

Answer (score 0):

The JS has a property to check the `parentNode` if is editable ([isContentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/isContentEditable)). This seems to be working well!

```
if (node.parentNode.isContentEditable === false) {
      node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(searchedWord, replacement);
}
```